# Blank pages after logging in or signing up on website. Laravel problem

Tags: php, laravel, web, xampp

Strange thing, I created a website with Laravel like 2 years ago and it was working just fine but now that I tried to open it and see it again, I'm facing some problems, the views work so fine before logging in or signing up to the system but ever since I sign up or log in, all pages go suddenly blank, I'm sp frustrated and I can't figure out the problem is where exactly, also when I check my DB, a new user been added to the table users according to the infos I signed up with, so it does the work but it doesn't show me the system.

Here's a part of my code:

RegisterController

```
public function create()
{
    return view('/register');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);

    if ($request->hasFile('photo')) {
        $user->photo = $request->photo->store('avatar');
    }

    if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
        $user->image = $request->image->store('avatar');
    }


    $user->save();

    $user->roles()->attach(Role::where('name', 'Elève')->first());

    auth()->login($user);

    return redirect('/');
}
```

routes

```
Route::get('/register', 'RegisterController@create');
Route::post('/register', 'RegisterController@store');
```

Does anyone have any clue? I will be so grateful if anyone shares their opinion with us. Thanks in advance!

Comment: any error in network tab of the console?

Comment: Which routes have issues? Is it after logging in? Or is it login page? The code redirect('/') is it working?

Comment: Have you checked for errors in your Laravel logs? They'd be located in `storage/logs` or `app/storage/logs`

Comment: Have you made any code changes or updated your composer dependencies since you last saw the site working?

Comment: @Spholt yes i had to update composer today :/ does that make it wrkng and how to fix it?

Comment: @Greedo hello, sorry to take this long to reply, I just checked the console it is also blank returning nothing

Comment: @RajeshPaudel I can log in to the system cuz everytime I want to log out and have back my welcome page working again, I just go to the URL: **127.0.0.1:1000/logout** which allows me to log out of the system and stay as a visitor on the system so I m not sure which one has the issues, can you help me find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this sort snippet of code in the user's password field

```
$user->password = Hash::make($request->password);
```

Try

```
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
```

Put this on your view to see any error

```
@php dump($errors) @endphp
```

Check your network tab to see the response code that's returned.
Also, make sure you have the `App\User` at the top of your controller.

Check the Laravel logs at `storage/logs/laravel.log`
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your kind of solution, after I added that line and imported 'use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;' to my RegisterController, the page is still going blank 
Then, I applied that code clearing the cache and regenerated the list of all classes that need to be included in the project and still nothing works
Finally I put the code inside the view hoping to see the error I can't see anything, the page is still blank, what can I do please??
Also, Yes of course I have the 'App\User' imported on Controller

Comment: SO STRANGE! I just checked Laravel logs, this is what I found **local.ERROR: Route [login] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\education finale\resources\views\layouts\edu.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\education finale\resources\views\layouts\edu.blade.php) {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Route [login] not defined. (View: C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\education finale\**

Comment: I think the error will help you solve the problem. You have to define the login route or you can use ```Auth::routes()``` helper class.

Comment: And if my contribution has helped you figured out what is wrong? Do accept my answer. 
Thanks.

Comment: no the route login is written correct the problem was with my DB, and some sort of table that contained roles for users, however thanks alot for helping me find out the problem where, you been so kind!